# Composer: Huge vendor folder

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

I am experimenting with Composer and coming from a RubyGems/Bundler background, it does exhibit some interesting behavior.

I tried creating a new Laravel project and to my surprise, I discover that I end up with a vendor folder that is beyond 70 megabytes in size.

While Laravel does offer a lot of functionality, I found the size to be bizarre, so I examined the contents of the vendor folder and discovered that it contains not just code, but also unit tests, documentation and entire git histories. For Swiftmailer, I even found lenghty RFC's for various e-mail standards.

While it's convenient to access specs and repository history for the dependencies, it does create a rather time-consuming deployment process and it litters the production server with irrelevant data.

I do understand that I could probably write an artisan command to "build" the app and dust off the dependencies by nuking all git histories, but it does seems like a dirty solution to a problem that has probably already been solved.

So the question is: Is there an approach to install composer dependencies, so only the code actually neccessary for running the (Laravel) app is downloaded?

#### Update: Using `--prefer-dist`

I have discovered that you can pass the `--prefer-dist` option when creating a new project, .e.g

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel my-new-project --prefer-dist
```

This makes Composer prefer zipped distributions over obtaining the source directly from the VCS (e.g. GitHub)

This rids you of the git histories and reduces the vendor folder to 17 megabytes. However, specs, documentation, e.g. is still included. So it would be nice if there was a way to push it down to a couple of megabytes.

Comment: Well, that's an interesting question as it should affect every framework relying on composer for it's dependencies.

Comment: When `--prefer-dist` is active Composer tries to take the zip file for each distribution, so if spec or doc files are excluded in `.gitattributes` they won't be downloaded.

Comment: 70M? So tiny! My `vendor` folder with Laravel 5.6 and four other small packages is 629M.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at this package:

https://github.com/barryvdh/composer-cleanup-plugin

You could even improve upon this, I don't know if it removes the `.git` repositories as well etc..

Answer (score 1):

My vendor folder has a size of about 17 MB. Not sure what went wrong with your installation, but 70 MB is not the size it should have. I'm using Laravel 4.1. As far as I remebmer I downloaded it from Github as .zip (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/master.zip) and then let Composer do the "install".

Comment: I've figured out that you can pass in the option `--prefer-dist`, which will make Composer prefer the zip packages over source repos, and since these zip packages come without the repository history, it slims that size dramatically. However, 17 mb is still too much, because it still contains specs and other runtime irrelevant stuff - SwiftMailer is the main culprit here.

Comment: Right, more than 6 MB. Well Laravel does not force you to use Swiftmailer.

Comment: I agree, but laravel/framework has SwiftMailer as a declared dependency, so if I begin postprocessing the vendor folder at will, I am asking for future trouble.

Comment: The size of Laravel 4 was often discussed. I also dislike it, Laravel 3 had a handy size of only ~3 MB. I have no idea how to shrink the size of L4.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with my project, vendor would take 2.1GBs, so I figured out in couple of tries deleting it and doing composer install, I should do next install after delete with **GIT Bash**, and it installed it better with only 40-50mb size, so my whole project takes about 100mb in size,

Good luck

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).